# Error! connect Hibernate and Postgresql on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, postgresql

When i run project on eclipse, errors appear:

> Jun 08, 2013 6:11:46 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version
>
> INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations
>
> {4.0.2.Final} Jun 08, 2013 6:11:46 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
>
> INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.2.2.Final} Initial SessionFactory
>
> creation failed. java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError Exception in
>
> thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError   at
>
> HibernateUtil.(HibernateUtil.java:13)     at
>
> PublisherDAO.addPublisher(PublisherDAO.java:5)    at
>
> BookApp.main(BookApp.java:12) Caused by:
>
> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError     at
>
> org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.reset(Configuration.java:309)     at
>
> org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.(Configuration.java:275)    at
>
> org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.(Configuration.java:279)    at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.(AnnotationConfiguration.java:50)
>
> at HibernateUtil.(HibernateUtil.java:8)     ... 2 more Caused
>
> by: java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>
> org.hibernate.internal.util.ConfigHelper.getResourceAsStream(ConfigHelper.java:170)
>
> at org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.(Environment.java:221)     ...
>
> 7 more

And code demo:

1)hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">postgres</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
        <property name="hibernate.default_schema">public</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
        <mapping class="Publisher"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

2)BookApp.java

```
import java.util.*;
import org.hibernate.*;
public class BookApp {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("hello world!");
        PublisherDAO dao=new PublisherDAO();
        dao.addPublisher("003", "Manning", "Mit");
    }

}
```

3)HibernateUtil.java

```
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;
public class HibernateUtil {
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    static{
        try{
            sessionFactory=new AnnotationConfiguration().configure()
                    .buildSessionFactory();

        }catch(Throwable ex){
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed. "+ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory(){
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

4)Publisher.java

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;

@Entity
@Table(name="publisher")
public class Publisher {
    private String code;
    private String publisher_name;
    private String address;

    @Id
    @Column(name="code")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=IDENTITY)
    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }
    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    @Column(name="publisher_name")
    public String getPublisher_name() {
        return publisher_name;
    }
    public void setPublisher_name(String publisher_name) {
        this.publisher_name = publisher_name;
    }

    @Column(name="address")
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

5)PublisherDAO.java

```
import java.util.*;
import org.hibernate.*;
public class PublisherDAO {
    public void addPublisher(String code, String name, String address){
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Publisher publisher=new Publisher();
        publisher.setCode(code);
        publisher.setPublisher_name(name);
        publisher.setAddress(address);
        session.save(publisher);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }
}
```

i effort very much, but errors aren't solve.Help me!

Comment: Can you also post content of your .classpath file here. I guess there is something wrong with project setup.

Answer (score 1):

They key part seems to be:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException 
at org.hibernate.internal.util.ConfigHelper.getResourceAsStream(ConfigHelper.java:170)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.(Environment.java:221)
```

This suggests that Hibernate is failing to read your configuration. Something is unexpectedly null. Since you didn't specify your exact Hibernate version I couldn't look at the source to say what, so I suggest that you go and do so. See what Hibernate is doing in your exact Hibernate version on line 170 of `ConfigHelper.java`, which should be within the `getResourceAsStream` method.

If you're still stuck, add the sources to your debug source path, then run your program under a debugger. Set the debugger to trap on uncaught exceptions (usually the default, but there might be a global exception handler you need to deal with). Or set a breakpoint at the line of interest. Then run the program. When it crashes, look back down the stack to see where it comes into contact with something you wrote.

Comment: Well, take a look at the relevant line of the Hibernate 4.2.2 sources then, or add them to your debugger and set a breakpoint.